# Using #ifdef in global template that gets used by class functions

Tags: c++, templates, macros, conditional-compilation

I have a global template

```
template <typename Derived>
double my_function(const MatrixBase<Derived>& m) {
    return m.determinant();
}
```

I would like to be able to change the `my_function` via compiler flag. For example:

```
template <typename Derived>
double my_function(const MatrixBase<Derived>& m) {
#ifdef NODET
    return 0;
#else
    return m.determinant();
#endif
}
```

If I now use `my_function` in any class function, I get an error:

```
error: there are no arguments to ‘my_function’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘my_function’ must be available [-fpermissive]
```

I think I could resolve this error by moving `my_function` into the class that calls it. However, several other functions and classes in my code use this template, so it would be problematic to move it into any one class.

I read several warnings on SO and other webpages that one should not use `#ifdef` macros if one has other workarounds. I wanted to use it nonetheless, because I wanted to make sure that the if-else statement gets completely resolved at compile time. Every run of my code call `my_function` several billion times, so  I also do not want to add any intermediate variables, keyword arguments, or if-else clauses in `my_function` that could make it even slightly slower than it currently is.

How can I get this to work? Or alternatively, how can I achieve what I want without using macros?

*EDIT*

In response to Peter's comment I tried the following

```
template <typename Derived>
double my_function(const MatrixBase<Derived>& m) {
    if constexpr (NODET) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return m.determinant();
    }
}
```

This throws an error when compiling with gcc and C++17:

```
error: expected ‘(’ before ‘constexpr’
  if constexpr (NODET)
```

But according to cppreference, constexpr is supposed to come before the brackets. How can I get this work?

Comment: The code that you have in your question [compiles fine](https://ideone.com/PRgYnI). Can you please post a [code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces your problem?

Comment: Most compilers need to see a definition of the template function in order to call it.  Use template specialisation rather than macros, usually.  C++11 and later, look up `if constexpr`.

Comment: @Peter That's C++17

Comment: @PasserBy - thanks, I typed too fast.

Comment: @Peter Thanks for the tip! I tried `if constexpr` with gcc and C++17. I get an error when compiling: `error: expected ‘(’ before ‘constexpr’
if constexpr(DYER_CONST)` That confuses me, because in the reference `constexpr` goes before the brackets, not inside. Am I doing something wrong? I can add the new code to my question to show what I did